# How to draw a curve line on Pixelmator

Tags: image-editing

This is probably one of the most important / useful feature in any image editing software - any knows how to draw curved line in Pixelmator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do in Pixelmator 1 is arcs using the oval selection tool. Select an area with the selection tool set to the circle/oval setting and then trace the selection (Edit -> Stroke) on a new layer. Once traced, erase the part of the trace you don't need. Reposition, stretch and mangle with the layer tools.

[Pixelmator 2 adds vector drawing capabilities](http://www.pixelmator.com/sneak-preview/). It'll be available this summer and it will be a free upgrade for anyone who [purchased Pixelmator 1 via the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/pixelmator/id407963104?mt=12).

Update: Pixelmator 2 was released via the App Store today and the pen tool lets you draw and manipulate curves now. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Pixelmator (1.x) is a raster-based image processing software and doesn't support curved line and other vector functions.

Edit: It seems that the next version will have some vector tools: http://www.pixelmator.com/sneak-preview/